# Corregir una function de javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, botón, function

Saludos chicos tengo el siguiente codigo

```
function botonver(a, b) {
imgnormal = "media/imagen/pdf.png";
tituloboton = "Ver PDF ";
botonpdf = "<img class = 'clase2' src = '" + imgnormal + "' width = '50%' />";
iniciotb = 4;

    return "<a title  = '" + tituloboton + b.substring(iniciotb) + "' target = '_blank' href = '" + a + "' >" + botonpdf + "</a>";
}
```

Me gustaria saber como puedo simplificarlo para utilizar variables fijas archivo y titulo, lo unico que varia es el numero y siempre sera el mismo numero es decir cuando desee mostrar el boton del archivo01 el titulo sera del mismo numero es decir archivo01, titulo01

Asi como esta debo colocar las salidas de la siguiente manera:

```
botonver(archivo07, titulo07)
```

Pero me gustaria saber como puedo implementar para hacer una salida con un codigo mas corto algo como:

```
botonver(07)
```

Un ejemplo de la salida que tengo funcionando es este:

```
function leccion02() {

    var archivo02 = ruta[02] + "Como hacer un Inicio.pdf";

    var titulo02 = "Hacer un Inicio Perfecto";

    contenidos = [
        {  a: "<h4 class = 'media-heading'>" + titulo02 + "</h4> texto.",
        b: botonver(archivo02, titulo02)
        },
    ];

    resultado = "";
    resultado += cabecera;

    for (key in contenidos) {

        resultado += "<div class = 'row well well-lg '> <div class = 'col-xs-12 col-sm-6 text-justify'>" + contenidos[key].a + "</div> <div class = 'col-xs-12 col-sm-6 text-center '>" + contenidos[key].b + "</div> </div>";

    };
    resultado += "</div> </div>";

    document.getElementById('contenido').innerHTML =
    resultado;

}
```

Pero no se como hacer que funcione como lo he descrito en mi consulta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeramente, tendrás que pasar tu valor como una cadena a la función. Intentar pasarlo como número será mucho más problemático, ya que JS quitará el cero de la izquierda.

Luego, usas el número para concatenarlo con el valor de `tituloboton` y en el `href` pones ya escrito `archivo` y concatenas con el parámetro `num` de forma dinámica.

Algo así:

```js
botonver("07");

function botonver(num) {
  imgnormal = "media/imagen/pdf.png";
  tituloboton = "Ver PDF " + num;
  botonpdf = "<img class = 'clase2' src = '" + imgnormal + "' width = '50%' />";
  //iniciotb = 4;
  var elLink = "<a title  = '" + tituloboton + "' target = '_blank' href = 'archivo" + num + "' >" + botonpdf + "</a>";
  console.log(elLink);
  return elLink;
}
```

Otra forma de hacerlo sería mediante el uso de [`document.CreateElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement). En ese caso, crearías un elemento `a` (enlace) y luego asignarías los datos a cada atributo del elemento.

El código queda mucho más claro así:

```js
botonver("07");

function botonver(num) {
  imgBoton = "<img class = 'clase2' src = 'media/imagen/pdf.png' width = '50%' />";
  var elLink = document.createElement('a');
  elLink.textContent = imgBoton;
  elLink.href = 'archivo' + num;
  elLink.title = "Ver PDF " + num;
  elLink.target = "_blank";

  console.log(elLink);
  return elLink;
}
```

Comment: He intentado con el codigo sugerido pero no logra ubicar el nombre del archivo ya que busca literal el archivo07 he editado mi pregunta a ver si me hago entender. Asi como esta funciona pero me gustaria simplificar ya que son como 300 botones en diferentes secciones y asi estaria logicamente ahorrando texto en el codigo.

Comment: @JoseMHerreraV entendí que los archivos se llamaban `archivo01, archivo01,  archivoNN...` ¿es así? ¿Están en la misma carpeta? Ten en cuenta que en `href` **tienes que poner la ruta correcta del archivo**, de lo contrario no funcionará. O sea, debería quedar así más o menos: `<a href="http://www.tu-dominio.com/carpeta/archivo07" ...` donde está el `href` tú puedes poner los valores fijos, tal y como se ha puesto la palabra `archivo`

Comment: No los archivos tienen cada uno su nombre particular, definidos por las respectivas variables archivo01 = nombrearchivo.pdf

Comment: Entonces no te explicaste bien en la pregunta. Si cada nombre de archivo varía, no puedes pasar solamente un número... sería imposible saber cómo se llama el archivo, por lo tanto tienes que pasar un parámetro con el nombre. O sea, esto que dices: *Pero me gustaria saber como puedo implementar para hacer una salida con un codigo mas corto algo como: `botonver(07)`*  es imposible si el nombre del archivo no sigue un patrón del tipo `archivo01, archivo02...`

Comment: Ok, comprendo, Gracias. Igual el codigo sugerido es valido para otros aplicativos..! y de seguro lo implemento en un futuro. Gracias

Comment: Incluso puedes retroceder todavía un poco, y cuando llamas a `leccion02()` pasarle en parámetro los datos a esa función. O sea, en vez de tener declarado el nombre del archivo y el título dentro de esa función, declararlo antes: `var archivo = ruta[02] + "Como hacer un Inicio.pdf";` var titulo = "Hacer un Inicio Perfecto";` luego cuando llamas a `leccion02` haces: `leccion02(archivo,titulo);` y la función estaría declarada así: `function leccion02(archivo,titulo){...` no sé si me entiendes lo que quiero decir. Es más, **podrías tener una sola función llamada `lecciones` para toda llamada.**

Comment: Comprendo, muy amable